# SelectedItem not updated

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP app with a listbox who is bound to a List of Enums to display the different options with a radio button.

What I want, is that when I select an item (for example yearly), that on the SelectedCategory the BudgetPeriod is changed to the enum yearly. What I tried is the following:

My Listbox:

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,0,12"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding BudgetPeriods}"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory.BudgetPeriod}">
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        <RadioButton Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected}" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListBox>

Selected Category Property:
 public CategoryViewModel SelectedCategory
        {
            get { return selectedCategory; }
            set
            {
                selectedCategory = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

List of enums:

```
public List<BudgetPeriod> BudgetPeriods => new List<BudgetPeriod>
    {
        BudgetPeriod.Monthly,
        BudgetPeriod.Yearly
    };
```

Unfortunately the Propety in SelectedCategory.BudgetPeriod is always Monthly (The first selection) and is not changing when I select something else.

The project is open source, so you can checkout the whole code aswell: https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyFox.Windows/tree/budget

Links to the relevant classes:
View Model:
https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyFox.Windows/blob/budget/Src/MoneyFox.Business/ViewModels/ModifyCategoryViewModel.cs

Model: 
https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyFox.Windows/blob/budget/Src/MoneyFox.Foundation/DataModels/CategoryViewModel.cs

View:
https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyFox.Windows/blob/budget/Src/MoneyFox.Windows/Views/ModifyCategoryView.xaml

View (code Behind):
https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyFox.Windows/blob/budget/Src/MoneyFox.Windows/Views/ModifyCategoryView.xaml.cs

Android Layout:
https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyFox.Windows/blob/budget/Src/MoneyFox.Droid/Resources/layout/activity_modify_category.axml

Comment: Does BudgetPeriod  fire the Property changed event?

Comment: You mean on the SelectedCategory? Yes it does. I have to add, that there is a similar implementation for android using the same VM with MvvmCross and it works there but not on Windows. So the VM in general is alright I guess.

Comment: can you please add the link to the github class in a comment?

Comment: Ah, good idea. I edited the original post with them. Please give me a hint if missed a relevant file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the binding in "TwoWay" mode :

```html
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory.BudgetPeriod, Mode=TwoWay}">
```